# jQuery - works in Firefox - returns Undefined in IE & Chrome

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, firefox, outerhtml

I have the following XML that I am using in several functions in a web page that uses jQuery.

```
var msgXML = "<XMLInput><Source></Source><MessageText></MessageText><SendTime></SendTime><Destination></Destination></XMLInput>",
msgXMLDoc = $.parseXML(msgXML),
$msgXML = $( msgXMLDoc );
```

In a function that makes use of the above in order to set values, as shown below:

```
$msgXML.find("Source").append(newSource);
$msgXML.find("MessageText").append(NewMessageTxt);
$msgXML.find("SendTime").append(currDateTime);
$msgXML.find("Destination").append(newDest);
var newXML = $msgXML.children(0).get(0).outerHTML;
```

The last line above sets newXML with the outerHTML that I am then passing into another function (to write it into a table).

In Firefox, the last line works fine & a console.log of `newXML` shows the XML I expected to see.  However, in both IE and Chrome, it returns **Undefined**.  What do you need to do to be able to use the XML data that is in outerHTML in all 3 browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: `.children(0)` doesn't make much sense, though i'm unsure if it's the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$msgXML.childNodes` to get this work in all browsers.